# How do you loop through 2D array with for loops

Tags: arrays, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    grid := [][]int{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6, 7},
    }
    for _, array := range grid[0] {
        for j := range array {
            fmt.Print(array[j], " ")
        }
        fmt.Println()

    }
}
```

This is what I have now and I am trying to traverse each column, but I get below  compile error

```
./prog.go:13:12: cannot range over array (type int)
```

grid is [][]int array. I am trying to set array to each column and traverse the column.

[PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/7quGWIIkSr-)

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Your range loop is perfectly fine**, The only problem is that if you are using two loops for 2D array, then why do you need to use **grid[0]** in the outer loop, just use **grid** it will work

Your updated working code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    grid := [][]int{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6, 7},
    }
    for _, array := range grid {
        for j := range array {
            fmt.Print(array[j], " ")
        }
        fmt.Println()

    }
}
```

Runnable example - https://play.golang.org/p/NIkhFOqyF6g

It is giving error because when you pass **grid[0]** to outer loop it will pass an integer value in inner loop, and it will give error **cannot range over array (type int)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing one variable name in your inner `range`.

From https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16:

> When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration. The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at that index.

The code below has the fix (runnable example at https://play.golang.org/p/6uaM2IEm9lR)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    grid := [][]int{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6, 7},
    }
    for _, col := range grid {
        for _, value := range col {
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
    }
}
```